# Apple tree looking dead with brown leaves and black bark

Tags: fruit-trees

I am not sure what is going on with my apple tree. 3 weeks back everything seemed fine and now the leaves the brown, the fruit is rotting and there is blackness at the bottom bark.

I have attached image of the current state. Any help is appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 2):

The blackened area at the base of the trunk is the likely cause - it indicates some type of infective fungal problem, possibly foot and butt rot. There isn't much you can do about it I'm afraid, you may well lose the tree, but it's worth inspecting the blackened area closely for signs of weeping, holes,soft areas or insect infestation. What sort of beetle/insect infestation or fungal problem there might be depends on what part of the world you are in.

Comment: I am in the midwest and new to tree maintenance. Three weeks back everything seemed to be all right and yesterday I see this. Its been raining at least twice a week so water is not a problem. I don't want to let this tree die. Will try my best to fix it and with any help I get on this platform.

Comment: Midwest? does that mean somewhere in the US or another country?If  its the US, which USDA zone are you in?

Comment: Precise location is Southern Wisconsin and the USDA zone is 5